# How come my execution result is correct, but watch list result is wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I wrote a c++ program, and when I'm using debug mode, 
I put a pointer type variable (say `m_pdummy`) into the watch list, but it shows "bad ptr";

If I expand this pointer(by clicking the "+" left to the name) and wants to see other variables under this pointer, all variables show "**expression cannot be evaluated**";

However, in my code, I wrote some output stuff, like:
`CString str;`
`DWORD d1;`
`d1 = m_pdummy->m_wgear;`
`str.Format("%d");`
`MessageBox(str);`
and then message box shows correct value;

But if I drag m_pdummy, d1, str into watch list, all of them says either "**expression cannot be evaluated**" or "**symbol not found**"; But this is impossible because message box could show values;

So what's the problem here?!

Best regards to whom read this,
Thanks!

Marson

Comment: Do you maybe have optimizations turned on? Are you really sure you're in debug mode?

Comment: yes i'm in debug mode, i use F10 to run the next step; optimization affects such things?!

Comment: Consider (assume each statement is its own line): `int foo(int x){ int y = x + 1; int z = y + 1; return z + 1; }`. You'd have a pretty dumb compiler if it didn't turn that into `int foo(int x){ return x + 3; }` when optimizing. Now consider you have optimizations turned on: there is no `y` or `z`.

Comment: cool, never knew that! so if i opened optimization, then it's normal if i open disassembly window and see no assembly code for line y=x+1 and z=y+1?

Comment: yep. An optimization rewrites your code, so that the assembly code that is generated no longer matches exactly what you wrote. But it should still have the same *result*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the code you are debugging with is not exactly the one running, or the VS Compiler optimize your code so some of the code doesn't exist anymore.
  In the case of the former, the breakpoint and debug value cannot be watched,  you should check out the code match the debugging one. I  come up with this when I register COM server a 'wrong' dll.
In the case of the latter, you should close the optimization option. Hope this will help you.

Comment: i think the running code matches the edited code, because the running code do reflect my changes; but the only problem is that I just cannot see correct value of this certain pointer "m_pDummy"; very werid case; thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

It *may* be that you're in the wrong stack frame. Those variables you list only exist according to their storage duration. If you're *outside* that duration (for example, before entering their function or after leaving it), the variable do not exist.

Example, say you have the function (line numbers on left):

```
20
21    int dbl (int x) {
22        int y = x + x + x;
23        y -= x;
24        return y;
25    }
26
```

The duration of `x` is only on lines `21` thru `25` (and `y` is `22` thru `25`). Any attempt to watch the variables outside of that duration will probably result in the message you're seeing.

This is true for objects as well, you won't be able to see member variables unless an object has been instantiated.

The other possibility is that, even if an object *has* been instantiated, you may need the full name, something like `myObject->m_pDummy`.

They're guesses based on limited available information, but that's the first things I'd be looking into.

Comment: hi thanks for the fast reply! i'll try the full name method; but may i ask what do you mean by "instantiated"?

Comment: ok i encounter even stranger case, for example: i put m_pDummy into watch list, when on line 21, it shows value 1, execute to line 22, shows value 2, to line 23, another value; however, i didnt do any changes to m_pDummy during these lines(including any changes to variables pointed by m_pDummy);